# Checking List for same numbers

Tags: python, list

Here is my code:

```
def generate_cards(self):


    self.player1_cards = [
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), ''],
        [random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91)],
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91),
         '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91)]
    ]

    self.player2_cards = [
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), ''],
        [random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '',
            random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), random.randint(1, 91)],
        [random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91),
            '', random.randint(1, 91), '', random.randint(1, 91)]
    ]

    for i in range(0, 3):
        ordered = iter(sorted(x for x in self.player1_cards[i] if x != ''))
        self.player1_cards[i] = [
            next(ordered) if x != '' else '' for x in self.player1_cards[i]]

    for j in range(0, 3):
        ordered1 = iter(
            sorted(x for x in self.player2_cards[j] if x != ''))
        self.player2_cards[j] = [
            next(ordered1) if x != '' else '' for x in self.player2_cards[j]]

    print("Player1:\n", self.player1_cards,
          "\nPlayer 2:\n", self.player2_cards)
```

In this code, im generating 2 cards for each player and sorting them. However i have to check card's rows if the generated numbers used only 1 time. I mean if there is 9 in player1_cards, no more 9 in this card.

Comment: Please ask a minimal and clear question.

Comment: Make the full deck of cards, use 'shuffle()' on it and then give first 9 cards to player1, and next 9 cards to player 2.

Comment: Can you please add more explanation to it with some sample input/ouput?

Comment: Can you explain the format of the cards? Why the nested lists with varying number of elements? Why the `''` in between some values but not in between others?

Comment: In this rows, some places are empty. I used ' ' these for see which places are free. @tobias_k

Answer (score 1):

```
def generate_cards():
    deck = list(range(1, 91))
    random.shuffle(deck)
    player1_cards = [deck.pop() for _ in range(9)]
    player2_cards = [deck.pop() for _ in range(9)]
```

Comment: Or `playerX_cards = [deck.pop() for _ in range(9)]`

Comment: Good suggestion

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but i didnt understand the code correctly. Can i create 3 rows for each cards? @tobias_k

Comment: I ran your code to understand what results you want, but still have questions. Please answer these questions: 1) Do you have in total 90 cards in your deck? 2) Each player should receive 17 cards in 3 groups: 6 cards, 6 cards, 5 cards?

Comment: @Alex   https://prnt.sc/riby87    You can check the link to understand, what i am trying to do.

Comment: @sonelekrikci ok, the picture almost clarified the thing. I just don't understand where these numbers come from: '8' for player 1 and '16' for player 2.

Comment: i didnt understand what you asking

Comment: These two numbers (8 and 16) are not like others, why? https://ibb.co/5kCJ9p2